# .NET 3.5SP1 ORM - database agnostic

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, orm

we're working on an application that digs data from an Oracle DB and a SQLServer one. In need for a (possibly free) ORM solution, I'd like to use Entity Framework, but it does not support Oracle.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Re DbLinq - definitely not abandoned - lots of activity: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/source/list

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate is an excellent .NET ORM solution. I have used it on many projects.

- http://www.hibernate.org/343.html

A more closed Microsoft kind of ORM solution is Deklarit. It works. It is probably easier for a novice to work with. However when you have problems you are more dependant on the Deklarit vendor. I personally would use NHibernate over Deklarit unless you are new to database tools and you are very fond of dev tools that integrate into Visual Studio.

- [http://www.deklarit.com](http://www.deklarit.com/)

Also see csharp-source.net for a list of Persistence frameworks:

- http://csharp-source.net/open-source/persistence

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is pluggable; there are meant to be a number of 3rd party Oracle providers for Oracle, such as [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) ([tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/tutorial_ef.html)).

Alternatively; [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) is a variant of LINQ-to-SQL/DataContext, and has Oracle support (plus is free).

Answer (score 0):

[NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) - [list of supported databases](http://www.hibernate.org/361.html)

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate